# MTU for WireGuard over IPv6

Tags: vpn, ipv6, wireguard

What would be the optional MTU for a virtual WireGuard link transmitting over IPv6 to avoid unnecessary fragmentation?

Here is how I approached the calculation:

- [IPv6 Header]   - 40 bytes
- [Some IPv6 Extensions] - X bytes

I take it that the MTU should be:

```
(MTU of Link Medium) - (40 + X)
```

Although, I am unsure as to what I should assume for the typical size of intermediate extensions given I am transmitting packets from a consumer ISP to a data center.

Comment: Remember that IPv6 does not have in-path fragmentation the way IPv4 does. IPv6 uses PMTUD to properly size packets prior to sending.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Wireguard uses a 16 byte header itself<sup>[[1]](https://www.wireguard.com/protocol/#subsequent-messages-exchange-of-data-packets)</sup> and the transport layer UDP an 8 byte header. Together with IPv6 in the outer network layer (40 bytes + options), that reduces the (path) MTU by at least 64 bytes.

For Internet links using additional encapsulation, the MTU is reduced further, e.g. 8 bytes for PPPoE.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming that it handles fragmentation internally, so you only need to reduce the MTU by the size of the outer encapsulation (which is not controlled by the interface.) But I could be wrong. If I am, I assume it would need to be reduced by an additional 8 bytes due to the existence of the UDP header.

Comment: You need to account for all additional overhead from encapsulation, with or without fragmentation (source-based only for IPv6). With an outer MTU of 1500 bytes and no IPv6 options that results in 1436 bytes inner MTU.